# I need help with my Blizzard Login

Tags: overwatch, blizzard

So apparently, I don't have a Blizzard login but I play Overwatch. I'm not sure if its because I play on a Playstation because I know you must have to login to play on a PC.

How can I get access to my Blizzard login?

Comment: This seems to be missing a question.  Are you asking how you can log into the same account on a PC as you use on a PlayStation?  What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Accounts aren't shared across platforms for Overwatch.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have a Blizzard (battle.net) account to play Blizzard games on a console. You can link your PSN/Xbox account to your existing battle.net account if you want to.

### Blizzard Site

- Log in to your Blizzard Account.
- Manage your Connected Accounts and click the Connect button next to
  the account you want to link.

### In-Game

- While in the game, open the main menu and choose Link Account. Note:
  This will temporarily disconnect you from Overwatch while you link
  your accounts.
- Choose Log In and fill in all necessary information. Choose Create
  Free Account if you don't have a Blizzard account.
- After your accounts are connected, choose Return to Connected
  Accounts.
- (Optional) Select the Redeem Digital Goodies button to claim your in-game
  goodies on your Blizzard account. Note: In-game goodies can only be
  claimed once, and cannot be undone.

[More info](https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/65162)